# Angular Js ng-change function runs on load

Tags: angularjs

I have Select box on which i have called a function on ng-change, but don't know why it run when page load. I don't want that function to call on load. I think it is not basic behaviour of ng-change.

```
<select class="form-control" name="state" id="state_id" ng-model="form.state" ng-change="getStateList(form.state)">
   <option value="">Select State</option>                                               
   <option ng-repeat="states in state" value="{{states.state_id}}" ng-selected="states.state_id == form.state_id"> {{states.name}} </option>
</select>
```

and in controller i have function as

```
$scope.getStateList = function(id) {
    $http.post('/statelist',{id:id}).then(function success(response) {
        $scope.state = response.data.state;
    });
}
```

and i load `$scope.city` on load on different call. but when i load page both the functions get called as `$scope.getStateList` should be call on chnage in select box. Whats wrong ?

and one more problem is ng-select is not working too.

Comment: Am not clearly understand  what you asking. can you provide your full controller and HTML code?

Comment: Question is simple.. ng-change should call function when we do change in select box.. but in my case it call function when page load on first time...

Comment: Your ng-change on the select is getCityList() whereas your function is listed as getStateList() - suggest you fix this.

Comment: May be you are using `form.state` from somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Change `ng-model="states.state_id" ng-change="getStateList(states.state_id)"` u want pass state id in ng-change event use this and try ..other wise u send whole scope values means send scope where u decalre in ng-repeat

Comment: but it still gives call to get getStateList() function